# Facebook comment plugin - How can I hide fbConnectWidgetFooter

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

Is there a way to hide fbConnectWidgetFooter, that text Facebook social plugin + icon, from the bottom.

If you see their example https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/ there is also class hidden_elem and hides it, but in my site it is visible.

Any ideas ? How can I add class hidden_elem ?

Answer (score -1):

This can be done with a CSS override normally:

```
.fb_iframe_widget{overflow: hidden;}
.fb_ltr{margin-bottom: -20px;} (or -35px, depends)
```

But keep in mind you're violating Facebook's legal rules and apparently they DO check on this. I've read about people getting in trouble with FB Legal.